# Calling function if ajax request is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button and 2 links, which makes an ajax request. If a request called by button is finished, I want to show alert. But I don't want to show the alert if I click on some link. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="ajax">Ajax</button>
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>

<div></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#ajax').click(function() {
    $("div").load("/echo/js/?js=button");

    $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
        alert('alert')
    });
})

$('a').click(function() {
    $("div").load("/echo/js/?js=link");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgyxzwj6/

Why if I click on the button and then I click some link, it shows the alert? And after first click on the button it shows alert only once. But if I click on the button second time, it shows alert two times. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Perform your alert**

You should use the callback function of jquery load to perform your alert:

```
$('#ajax').click(function() {
    $("div").load("/echo/js/?js=button", function() {
        alert('alert');
    });
});

$('a').click(function() {
    $("div").load("/echo/js/?js=link");
});
```

> Callback Function
>
> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.

from the jquery API and for more information about `load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Here is the updated fiddle for your case: http://jsfiddle.net/55rpfe0w/

**2. the ajaxStop handler**

Your code...

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    alert('alert')
});
```

...the event handler is also called when you do your ajax request with the links.

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are
>   any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers
>   the ajaxStop event.

from jquery API: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

**3.the multiple time alert**

> And after first click on the button it shows alert only once. But if I
>   click on the button second time, it shows alert two times. How can I
>   fix that?

The reason is, that you set the handler for the event `ajaxStop` in your click function and every click you do on your button you set another event handler and so:

> Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStop() method are executed at this time.

from jquery API: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Answer (score 0):

[You can pass a function as the second parameter to the load function, this passed function will get called when the `load` function completes.](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

If you don't want any function to run, you don't have to pass it anything, just like you're doing in the `$('a').click` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/rgyxzwj6/1/

```
$('#ajax').click(function() {
    $("div").load("/echo/js/?js=button", function() {
      alert('alert');
    });
})

$('a').click(function() {
    $("div").load("/echo/js/?js=link");
})
```